# Как на C# реализовать копирование с возможностью продолжения?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, файлы

Как на C# реализовать копирование с возможностью продолжения с месте где произошел разрыв?

Допустим, большой файл копировался, сеть упала и нужно:

1. Понять, что файл действительно не был полностью скопирован
2. Продолжить с места остановки.

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает вариант, который реализован в любом браузере - линейная докачка тупо по размеру?

Comment: Если можете читать по-английски, то посмотрите [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270216) вопрос. Возможно, это то, что вам нужно.